# Watir - Screenshot for IE is not proper

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir, webpage-screenshot

I am using Watir with Ruby.

I need to save screenshots. but it is improper screenshot.
Could you please help me out.

This is my code.

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
browser.maximize
browser.bring_to_front

browser.screenshot.save "C:/screenshot/jones.png"
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: What is improper about the screenshot you get?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you are using Watir-Classic as opposed to Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: There is only white blank space in the body of screenshot. only tab is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Following code segments did a proper screenshot in IE for me without using `maximize` and `bring_to_front`. You can try this:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto 'www.google.com'

browser.screenshot.save "C:/screenshot/jones.png"
```

I am using following versions:

- ruby 2.3.0
- watir 6.2.1
- Windows 8.1